# Poor query with table scans occasionally takes hours on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My application uses a MariaDB database which I try to keep isolated, but one particular user goes straight to the database and started complaining today after 6 weeks without incident that one of their queries slowed down from 5 mins (which I thought was bad enough) to over 120 mins.

Since then today it has sometimes been as fast as usual, sometimes slowing down again.

This is their query:

```
SELECT MAX(last_updated) FROM data_points;
```

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE data_points (
  seriesId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  modifiedDate DATE NOT NULL,
  valueDate DATE NOT NULL,
  value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  last_updated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CONSTRAINT pk_data PRIMARY KEY (seriesId, modifiedDate, valueDate),
  KEY ix_data_modifieddate (modifiedDate),
  KEY ix_data_id (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_data_seriesid FOREIGN KEY (seriesId)
  REFERENCES series(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
  COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  MAX_ROWS=222111000;
```

and this is the EXPLAIN:

```
id      select_type     table       type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1       SIMPLE          data_points ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL            NULL    224166191
```

The table has approx 250M rows and is growing relatively fast.

I can coerce the user into doing something more sensible but in the short term I'm keen to understand why the query duration is going crazy today after 6 weeks of calm. I'll accept the first answer that can explain that.

Comment: "I'll accept the first answer that can explain that." column last_updated isn't indexed

Comment: The obvious answer is that it's doing a table scan because there is no index on the `last_updated` column. I don't have an explanation (and I doubt you will find one) for why it took 5 minutes one week and then 120 minutes the next week. The prior speed might be because the user executes the query frequently and the result was indexed, or the new slowness might be due to a sudden increase in rows, or the new number of rows prompting the query optimizer to use a different query plan that was less efficient...Or a number of other things. It's hard to tell though.

Comment: Just index that column and be done with it.. modern MySQL versions and InnoDB engine versions can do this without downtime nowadays with online DDL make sure to check with the correct documentation link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT MAX(last_updated) FROM data_points;` is easily optimized:

```
INDEX(last_updated)
```

That index will make that `MAX` be essentially instantaneous.  And it will avoid pounding on the disk and cache (see below).

Two things control the un-indexed speed:

- The size of the table, which is "growing relatively fast", and
- [This is probably what you are fishing for.]  How much of the table is cached when the query is run.  This can make a 10x difference in the speed.  You can partially test this claim thus:

Restart mysqld; time the query; time it again.  The first run had to hit the disk a lot (because of the fresh restart); the second may have found everything in RAM.

Another thing that can mess with the timings:  If some other 'big' query is run and it bumps blocks of this table out of cache, then the query will again be slow.

Of relevance:  Size of table, value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and amount of RAM.

On an unrelated topic...  That `PRIMARY KEY (seriesId, modifiedDate, valueDate)` seems strange.  A PK is must be unique.  Dates (datetime, etc) are likely to have multiple entries for the same day/second; so can you be sure of uniqueness?  Especially with 2 dates?

(More)

Please explain the meaning of each of the 4 dates.  And ask yourself if they are all needed.  (About half the bulk of the table is those dates!)

The table has an `AUTO_INCREMENT`; is it needed by some other table?  If not then *either* it could be removed, *or* it could be used to assure that the PK is unique.

To better help you, we need to see more of the queries.

Comment: That is exactly what I was fishing for - makes perfect sense now. The  primary key is possibly sub-optimal. It is a time series db, and that data_points table is also de-normalised. Not my decision. Really the `valueDate` is the question. Currently some queries (not mine) query on the valueDate field when I think for performance sake they should just grab all the valueDates and filter it downstream.

Comment: BTW can you recommend a good MariaDB DBA guide, book, or course?

Comment: @Adam - Re DBA guides:  Search for MySQL books.  95% of what they say will apply to MariaDB; and there are more of them.

Comment: @Adam - and I added some more to my Answer.